# Data Loader CLI

Tags: data-loader, data-export

I am trying to export data using CLI data Loader. Can I  dynamically assign the export file name with the system date and time stamp.

Any suggestions would be appreciated!

Thanks!

Comment: Given CLI uses Spring Framework, you would need to search and see if there is a way to return the current date time with that framework. I just did a few searches and didn't find anything straightforward. Most results appeared to require adding a method to the jar file - which means recompiling and building your own version of CLI (I would not suggest this); maybe [dataloader CLI](https://github.com/forcedotcom/dataloader) has one natively. Given the framework supports it, I would say yes, it's possible... just not sure how to go about marking up the `process-conf.xml` to do so.

Comment: Even I'm facing same issue.
Anyone have answer to this??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unless someone finds a way to do it from within data loader, I'd set up the .bat job to rename the files after the extraction is run.